# Find distinct values in a column if the dataframe containts list in columns

Tags: python, pandas

lets assume we have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [[1,2], [1,2], [2,1]], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

col1 col2
[1, 2] A 
[1, 2] B
[2, 1] C
```

Where I have a list in a column in the dataframe, how can I count the distinct values in each column?
The function `df.nunique()`is not working it gives this error: `TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index :97A::SAFE')`

The expected output would be:

```
col1 2
col2 3
```

I need a solution which is appliciable over more columns, my original dataframe will have several columns and I will not know which one contains a list and which one not.

Comment: Do you want the number of distinct values *per cell*, or *per column* (col1 in your example)?

Comment: columns, as you can see in the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no type where equality of data and equality of string representation can be different, I would convert the whole dataframe to string:

```
df.astype(str).nunique()
```

For your example dataframe is gives as expected:

```
col1    2
col2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: you mean `nunique()`, but it is working, the function does not overwrite my original types of the columns right?

Comment: @PV8: You are right, the type is changed on a temporary dataframe, and the original one is left unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

For the column containing lists, you can map the values to `tuples`, *which are hashable*, and then use `nunique`:

```
df.col1.map(tuple).nunique()
# 2
```

---

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.map(tuple)
df.nunique()

col1    2
col2    3
dtype: int64
```

---

If you do not know which columns might contain lists:

```
df.applymap(tuple).nunique()

col1    2
col2    3
dtype: int64
```

Or checking specifically which columns contain lists:

```
cols = [i for i, ix in enumerate(df.loc[0].values) if isinstance(ix, list)]
df.iloc[:,cols] = df.iloc[:,cols].applymap(tuple) 
df.nunique()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it for all columns in the dataframe? my original frame have several columns, and I do not know where i have some lists in

Comment: Okay let's try and do this more generalisable @PV8

Comment: Now my original dataframe (Not in this posts) has the error: `("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index :13A::STAT')`, do you think NaN values are a problem?

Comment: now i get the list error again: `("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index :97A::SAFE')`

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the unique values across the column, you can do

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(np.vstack(df['col1'].values))
```

and to get the number of unique values:

```
len(np.unique(np.vstack(df['col1'].values)))
```

You can also use `np.hstack` or `np.concatenate` instead of `np.vstack`, but here, I wanted to preserve the two-dimensionality of the column values.

Comment: same remark as for the other posts, any possibility to run this automatically over all columns? my original dataframe will have more columns